# Looking for a Gulp plugin that will skip markdown files based on particular header attributes

Tags: gulp

I have markdown files that look like this

```
---
name: Some Name
date: '2013-09-09'
isCool: true
---
really cool text
```

I want to have a gulp task that only lets markdown through that has a particular property, for example isCool = true.

So I would imagine something like this

```
gulp.src('source/content/*/*.md')
.pipe(mdPrune({
    isCool: true
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/content/cool'));
```

then only the markdown that had an isCool attribute in the header would end up the build/content/cool folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) would work.

```
const filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task('default', function () {

      // return true if want the file in the stream
  const myFilter = filter(function (file) {

    let contents = file.contents.toString();
    return contents.match('isCool: true');
  });


  return gulp.src(['./src/*.md'])    
    .pipe(myFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('md'));
});
```

That will allow the file through if `isCool: true` is anywhere in the file.  If that is a problem, just work on the regex to restrict it to the line after the `date` entry for example.

[The filter could also be defined outside of any task if it might be reused elsewhere or you just prefer it that way.

Comment: ok thanks, I guess I can combine gulp filter with frontmatter to do const fm = require('front-matter'); const atts = fm(contents).attributes; return Boolean(atts.isCool) - in case isCool unspecified